# Preloading VPAID Flash ads - not possible/allowed? why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vast, video-ads

With VAST complaint video ads, you may get a "nested" VAST (VAST Wrappers), which will eventually yield a MediaFile that is a media that you could preload (e.g. MP4/WebM/flv, etc.).

However in the case of VPAID (flash, yuck!), which contains swf as the media files, at the end of the wrappers chain there lies yet another swf - for example, an "ad manager" swf.

So the effect of preloading a VPAID ad is essentially not very useful, because you could not extract the actual media file for preloading merely by inspecting the VAST XMLs. At best - you may preload the final ads manager swf.

The final swf, when played, may then begin to fetch ads from different providers (e.g. brightroll, liverail, etc.), and this process takes a while. At the end of this, an ad might pop up.

Is it allowed to try to preload the actual eventual ad media, or to find out if there is a "fill" (an ad media will be yielded by the ads manager)? For example, by "playing" the ads manager swf in the background, hidden and muted, this might be possible, but it sounds a bit fishy (what if the user eventually does not reach the point where the ad should actually be shown? it would count as fraud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No,
When you load the VPAID swf --> the ad server count impression and start the bid between the ads providers.
You can only load the swf when the user is watching the ad/movie.

Comment: Hi Itay. Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to work around this limitation? I mean, if my flash is loading an external flash (e.g. a LiveRail Ads Manager), can I (technically) load and start it, and pause in case of a VPAID "AdImpression" event? The VPAID object does not have a pause function, so I guess some workaround can be applied (something like reducing the stage framerate to 0 in the as3 code that loads the vpaid object)?

Comment: nice question for the liverail/facebook tech guys - i dont know how they count the impressions - by url hit or by the impression track event- usually in VPAID all the tracking done internally.